# Since update to XCode 9.3, I can't archive my project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, archive, xcode9.3

An interesting thing happened this morning, I updated Xcode to version 9.3, and after that, I can't archive my project. I can build it, run it on the device, but when I try to archive it, I get that I am missing some modules, like Alamofire, etc...

[image]

[image]

I am using cocoapods as dependency manager. And everything worked fine until this morning. Does anyone have the similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reset Cocoa Pod

Remove `Pod` from your project and add again.

or

try `sudo pod repo update` or `pod repo update`

---

And one more importance thing you must be missing is:

#### Set your command line tool version, in your Xcode.

You can download latest command line tool from [Apple Download Portal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12), if you have paid apple developer account/id.

Here is current stable Xcode Tools and supporting command line tool download link. (Ensure you'are logged in using premium developer account on Apple Developer Account to access these links)

> **Xcode 10**
>
> - [Xcode 10 - Beta 2](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_Beta/Xcode_10_Beta.xip)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 10 Beta 2) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta_2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10_Beta_2.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 10 Beta 2) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10_Beta_2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10_Beta_2.dmg)
>
> **Xcode 9**
>
> - [Xcode 9.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
> - [Xcode 9.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.3) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg)

Once you've latest command line tool installed in your system, set it from Xcode Menu.

> **(Xcode Menu Items) Xcode ► Preferences ► Location ► Command Line Tool ► Select appropriate command line tool**

[image]

[image]

---

#### Update Alamofire in your pod file.

Try this: [Alamofire Installation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation)

`pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'`

Comment: no change, and alamofire is not the only module that it can't find. Same for Kingfisher

Answer (score 1):

Can you ensure that you have **Swift version 4.1** when running `xcrun swift -version`

Also try to build your project without Alamofire (comment it in Podfile), then compile again with Alamofire.

Moreover are you sure you have opened the **.xcworkspace** instead of the **.xcodeproj** ? I know it might be dumb to ask, but it happens :)

Comment: Apple Swift version 4.1 (swiftlang-902.0.48 clang-902.0.37.1), removing and adding alamofire did not fix it. .xcworkspace is opened. What's interesting that I can build it and run it, I only get these errors while trying to archive

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you have accepted apple's agreement go to your apple account. I have recently faced this issue after updating my xcode to 9.3 swift 4.1
https://developer.apple.com/account/